# How do I change cors domain of geth metrics?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

I am trying to connect the output of geth metrics of a local node to Grafana.
I am initializing my node using the following geth command:

```
geth --datadir "n1" --nodiscover --networkid "4013" --metrics --metrics.addr "localhost"  --metrics.port "30301"
```

I can see the expected output when I navigated to `http://localhost:30301/debug/metrics/prometheus`.
Even curl in powershell also returns the output.

Now when I try to import with the url as a Data Source in Grafana (and using browser access) the JS console outputs the following

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:30301/debug/metrics/prometheus/api/v1/query' from origin 'https://jhaendar.grafana.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I know I can set cors domain for the HTTP server, is there any way to set it for metrics server as well?

Answer (score 1):

you can add `--rpccorsdomain jhaendar.grafana.net` or `--rpccorsdomain=*`